# Join Column delete in JPA

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table C which contains the two column one for table A id, and another for table B id. 
I need to remove some rows from the table C but it is not working. I am using JPA and spring, Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

I need to delete the record in C table, it has been failing due to foreign key constraint.
I have service class for C.

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class C {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "table_c", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "a_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "b_id") })
    private List<B> devices = new ArrayList<B>();


}

public String deleteC(@RequestParam("cid") long cId,
            Model model) {
        service.delete(cId);
        return "Success";
}
```

Comment: If you want anyone to bother answering your question you have to create a self contained example or at least narrow down your problem as much as possible. What exception do you get when you try to remove it?

Comment: Exactly. show us what you are working on. post your code. mention about the error trace. what did YOU do to try to resolve it?

Comment: I added the example code.